# PrimeFaces built-in CRUD?

Tags: primefaces

I'm pretty new to PrimeFaces and I'd need to setup a basic CRUD User Interface. From the showcase I can see there is a built-in Datatable parameter named editable to enable editing. I wonder if there is any built-in feature to enable also Adding and Deleting items. 
If not, what would be the simplest way to achieve it ? Maybe using a Dialog component to collect the new items ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get a CRUD would be to reverse engineer it. Create your tables in a database and in Netbeans 7 or 8 (I use 8) create

1. Entity classes from database
2. JSF pages from entity classes

During the second point you can choose between Primefaces and plain JSF. If you prefer, you could also skip the first point and code the entity classes yourself instead, and tell the server to create the tables on start.

This will get a full CRUD running, complete with theming, menustructure and templating, using primefaces, facelets, beans, custom entity converters, EJB's, entities and JPA.

I like most of the generated code quite well and there is a lot to learn from it as a beginner. The result is a full page for the list and dialogs (via `ui:include`'s) for create, view and edit.

I'd think Eclipse has something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it !